# Какие есть варианты обмана DoubleProperty в javafx

Tags: java, javafx

Необходимо, чтобы событие изменения возникало при `set` даже если новое значение равно старому.

Comment: Есть предложение создать для таких целей отдельный listener: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43393423/how-to-make-javafx-property-listener-to-fire-an-event-even-if-the-oldvaule-and-n#43393788

Comment: Не подходит, так как в таком случае не работают биндинги.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class MySimpleDoubleProperty extends SimpleDoubleProperty{
        @Override
        public void set( double newValue ) {
            if (get() == newValue){
                super.set(newValue + 0.0000000000001);
            }else {
                super.set(newValue);
            }
        }
}
```

Есть ли варианты повеселее, без "обмана" ?